# Multithreading in Tkinter

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I am new to Python and Tkinter but I was wondering if I could do Multithreading in Tkinter.

I have a `Restaurant Simulation` program and whenever it accepts an order, this is what should happen:

1) Timer that counts down and shows how many seconds are left before the order is done

2) While the Timer is counting, I want to create another instance of the `Restaurant Simulation` so that it could accept another order.

This is what I have tried:

```
from Tkinter import *

class food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []
    def cookOrder(self,type):
        if type is 'AA': #Cook Barf
            self.inventory[0]+=1        
class Restaurant():
    def Callback(self,root):
        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
            root.destroy()
    def MainMenu(self):
        self.Main = Tk()
        self.Main.grid()
        Title = Label(self.Main,text = "Welcome to Resto!",font=("Bauhaus 93",20))
        Title.grid(columnspan=6)

        RestoMenu = Button(self.Main,text = "Order Food",command = lambda:self.Restaurant_Menu('AA'),font=("High Tower Text",12))
        RestoMenu.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.Main.mainloop()

    def Restaurant_Menu(self,type):
        self.Main.destroy()
        self.setCookTime(type)

    def setCookTime(self,type):
        self.MainMenu() #This is not working as I planned it to be
        self.cookTimer = Tk()
        self.timeLabel = Label(text="")
        self.timeLabel.pack()
        if type is "AA":
            self.Tick(10,type)
        self.cookTimer.mainloop()
        self.cookTimer.wm_protocol ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.Callback(self.cookTimer)) #Getting TCL Error
    def Tick(self,time,type):
        time -=1
        if time ==-1:
            food.cookOrder(type)
            self.cook.destroy()
        else:
            self.timeLabel.configure(text="%d" %time)
            self.cookTimer.after(1000, lambda: self.Tick(time,type))

Food = food()
Resto = Restaurant()
Resto.MainMenu()
```

Now, the problem with the code is, it is not creating another instance of the `Restaurant` while the countdown is going on. Any help?

Plus, how do you ask the user for the confirmation of exiting program when he clicks the exit button while the timer is ticking, using `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`?

Comment: for asking for confirmation, make a method,use `tkFileDialog` for asking the user & call it using `root.wm_protocol ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", mymethod) `

Comment: & how about `Resto.MainMenu` instead of `self.MainMenu()`

Comment: @shaktimaan Tried replacing `self.MainMenu()` into `Resto.MainMenu` but still both windows are not working.

The Timer is not showing and so does the Restaurant Simulation